# How to make series subform in the main form by (infinity)adding button?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

This is the idea what I would like to get it. I am using Access-VBA but I am struggling to make series like this. Could you please give me an idea how to proceed it.
Thank you in advance.

[image: Forms]

**EDIT 2**

How to hide second form like this?

[image: Forms2]

**Edit 3**

Ok let me make a clear picture.
Imagine that you have one form which requires to enter family member's data for each family. So different family has different number of members. Some family has 5, some has 4 ...

The default page shows only one form for one person so it's |family 1| = area. This form also requires to fill "name/last name/address/whatever..." = width/lenght/xxx for the first person. And then second one needs to be added with the same form "name/last name/address/whatever..." AGAIN by clicking "+" sign until it covers the whole members.

Then second family members also needs the same.

Comment: Use a continuous form?

Comment: Why don't you use just continuous subform with fields like on your picture? New set of fields will appear when you add new row

Comment: @SergeyS. Would you mind show me the example of "continuous subform with fields " ? Little bit confuse how to set the number of forms too

Comment: Just create a form based on table or updateable query with fields like on your picture, make it continuous and it will show as many rows as you have in the query, will look very similar to your picture

Comment: @SergeyS. I got the continuous forms but how can I set visible/invisible forms from second onward ( one form by one click)?

Comment: @Andre Do you have any idea for edit 2?

Comment: Those are not forms, they are records. If you only want to show blank new record row, set 'main' form as Single and DataEntry Yes. There is no subform. Form will open to just new record row and only records entered in that session will display and can be navigated until form is closed and reopened.

Comment: @June7 What if I would like to open a new record form the same page as main form. How can I do it?

Comment: It is just not clear what you want. Perhaps you just need to move to new record row. Can use the intrinsic navigation features of form or write code behind custom buttons. Have you completed an introductory tutorial book to learn the basics of relational database, Access functionality, coding?

Comment: @June7 Ok, Please look at edit 3. Maybe you can get a clear picture.

Comment: Button "+" should add new row to your table with areas, "-" should delete or hide current row, then it will look like you need

Comment: @SergeyS. this is exactly what I want. I did it with continuous forms as you suggested but I could not set what you have mentioned with button + for adding and  - for deleting.

Comment: Sorry, not clearer. All I can comprehend is that you want to add a new record. So navigate to new record row and enter data. However, if you don't want to repeat info like Address, then use two related tables. One for family info record and then dependent table for each family member info. Then build a form/subform arrangement.

Comment: Cross-post https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=303656

Comment: @June7 that's post is me. all contents are the same.

Comment: @SergeyS. "Button "+" should add new row to your table with areas" >> should I work with the table?